# Postgresql - Rule with On Conflict Statement

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgres with columns `link(PK), person, places and date`. I would like to create a rule that when insert is command is issued from my backend program then if there is a conflict on the link column it would do an `upsert` ( update the `person, places and date`) columns for the same link. I cannot figure out the format of the rule. Below is pseudo code of what I am looking for.

```
Create Rule rssmodel as on 
INSERT into public.rssmodel
On conflict (link)
do UPDATE  public.rssmodel
    set person = data, places=data, date=data
```

Comment: That syntax is completely wrong. Just use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` explicitly. You might also get away with a `BEFORE` trigger for that, but there is always a small race condition with such triggers.

Comment: I did say it’s a pseudo code. It would be helpful to provide the code.

Comment: I see. You cannot replace `INSERT` with `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` using a rule, because that would read to an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to achieve that:

```
CREATE RULE rssmodel_insert AS ON 
INSERT TO public.rssmodel
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from rssmodel where NEW.link = link)
    DO INSTEAD 
UPDATE  public.rssmodel
    SET person = NEW.person, places = NEW.places, date = NEW.date WHERE link = NEW.link;
```